# How to load TimeSeriesData from non-continuous csv files

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I need to load a all csv files in a folder to train a time series model (PyTorch Lightening).

The issue is that while the rows within a file are continuous (t, t+1, etc.), there is a break between files.

How do I correctly deal with this? Do I pad them with seq_len?

This is how I currently load one file. Since this is PyTorch Lightening, it's hard to give a standalone working example, but I believe, the trick should probably be somewhere in setup or TimeseriesDataset.

Perhaps in setup, I should just load an X1 from csv1 and X2 from csv2, and concatenate them together with padding in between? What padding should that be? zeros?

Or should I do a check each time TimeseriesDataset is used to see if the timestamps in X are continuous? That seems inefficient.

```
def setup(self, stage=None):
    
    path = './file.csv'
    
    df = pd.read_csv(
        path, 
        sep=',', 
        infer_datetime_format=True, 
        low_memory=False, 
        na_values=['nan','?'], 
        index_col='Time'
    )

   X = df['cols'] # here I select the columns I want, not the issue at hand
   y = df['label'] # here I select the label, not the issue at hand


    X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.25, shuffle=False
    )


def train_dataloader(self):
    train_dataset = TimeseriesDataset(self.X_train, 
                                      self.y_train, 
                                      seq_len=self.seq_len)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, 
                              batch_size = self.batch_size, 
                              shuffle = False, 
                              num_workers = self.num_workers)
    
    return train_loader



class TimeseriesDataset(Dataset):   
    '''
    Custom Dataset subclass. 
    Serves as input to DataLoader to transform X 
      into sequence data using rolling window. 
    DataLoader using this dataset will output batches 
      of `(batch_size, seq_len, n_features)` shape.
    Suitable as an input to RNNs. 
    '''
    def __init__(self, X: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray, seq_len: int = 1):
        self.X = torch.tensor(X).float()
        self.y = torch.tensor(y).float()
        self.seq_len = seq_len

    def __len__(self):
        return self.X.__len__() - (self.seq_len-1)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.X[index:index+self.seq_len], self.y[index+self.seq_len-1])
```

The data consist of csv files with timestamp and features, something like the below. Different files may have the same timestamps, but they are both used to train the same model.

```
2020-01-01 11:00:00,130.85,130.89,129.94,130.2,4968.55433,0.9908333333333346,-0.004967520061138764,0,0,0,0,False,2.0,128.39,2.0,128.39
2020-01-01 12:00:00,130.21,130.74,130.15,130.2,3397.90747,0.9600000000000014,0.0,0,0,0,0,False,2.0,128.39,2.0,128.39
2020-01-01 13:00:00,130.2,130.47,130.11,130.3,4243.6064,0.9171428571428574,0.0007680491551460555,0,0,0,0,False,2.0,128.39,2.0,128.39
2020-01-01 14:00:00,130.31,130.75,130.26,130.44,3668.90166,0.8886666666666675,0.0010744435917113826,0,0,0,0,False,2.0,128.39,2.0,128.39
2020-01-01 15:00:00,130.47,130.71,130.14,130.24,4147.17413,0.8674222222222244,-0.0015332720024531232,0,0,0,0,False,2.0,128.39,2.0,128.39
```

So I might have 2 files like this, it could be stock ticker data and each file belongs to another ticker.

TimeSeriesDataloader will create tensors of seq_len x num_features, e.g. 10 x 9 as X, and the last value in the label column at time 10 as y.  Seq_len is the lookback period used during training and RNN.

If I were to just concatenate the 2 csv files, there would be an issue, because the time stamps are not compatible, i.e. there should be no X sampled that contains data from both csv1 and csv2. Each sampled X should be either from csv1 or from csv2.

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the data you are using, how the data looks and how it is supposed to look.

Comment: I have clarified the question according to your suggestion.

Comment: So this means you have duplicate timesteps in your DataFrame and that is not desirable? If that is the case, have you tried to drop the duplicates?

Comment: No that's fine. The issue is that, because it's an RNN, there is an input time window for creating X. I don't want X to be from two different csv files.